# Munin CPU usage graph doesn't go all the way to 100% on a physical server

Tags: munin

On a physical X86 server, the cpu's graph is not well draw. Basically the sum of all cpu's usages (system,user, nice, idle, etc) don't reach the 3200% (32 cores)

See the [image here](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist146540/image.png)

I have already search in the forums and applied the solutions there:

- Increase the maximum of the graph (rrdtool tune $x --maximum 42:3300);
- Update the munin client;

And nothing worked. Could you suggest any additional solutions?

Thanks to all.

Comment: I'm sorry. What *does* it show?

Comment: The graphic is like this [link] http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist146540/image.png

Comment: Could you try running the plugin manually a few times, so we can see wrong output (and, preferably, right output)?